# Uninitialized local variable 'b' used

Tags: c++

```
int a,b,c; 
a=b++, c++; //error here
```

I'm trying to test if `a` will get the value of `c++`

Error Message:

Uninitialized local variable 'b' used

Uninitialized local variable 'c' used

EDIT:
I read this on the internet http://www.studytonight.com/cpp/operators-and-their-types.php, but it is wrong that's what other user's say

Comment: "I'm trying to test if a will get the value of c++" so... what's the value of `c++`?

Comment: maybe initialize `b` and `c`!?

Comment: How can a variable be incremented if it "doesn't have" an initial value?

Comment: Any table of C++ operator precedence, for example [here](http://web.ics.purdue.edu/~cs240/misc/operators.html), will show you how to parse this expression.

Comment: You might try `a = 0, 42;` to test comma.

Comment: @user3415509 neither, `a` nor `b`, nor `c` have a value, from that perspective your assertion really makes no sense, i'd suggest reading [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)

Comment: The clue is in the error message. You need to give `b` and `c` an initial value. If you don't they could contain any random value.

Comment: http://www.studytonight.com/cpp/operators-and-their-types.php here's the source, last page.

Comment: As it happens, cppquiz has a question about this: http://cppquiz.org/quiz/question/120

Comment: @user3415509, That explanation is wrong in multiple ways. First, no comma operator is used in `int a,b,c;` Second, it's flat out incorrect regarding the behaviour of the second line. And right above that it says C++ has a `>>>` operator? It's super easy to verify that it doesn't. The unsigned right shift operator is simply `>>` applied to unsigned operands.

Comment: "here's the source" - sadly, that example is incomplete.  as you discovered, since your compiler is issuing error messages.  Fix the error messages and try again.

Comment: @chris - good catch on the comments at that tutorial "explaining" the behavior of both those lines - I didn't even read that far.  Hopefully those errors aren't generally indicative of the quality of that tutorial, or the OP is going to have a hard time learning C++ there ...  (Just read your revised comment pointing out the tutorial also claims there's an operator `>>>`.  Yeah, I suggest the OP find a different - better! - tutorial!  Or proceed to learn C++ by finding all the ways in which this one is wrong!

Comment: Checking a few other pages, it looks like an extremely bad tutorial for C++. Not only does it contain errors, like in this example, but also non-standard terms like "equivalence operator" instead of "equal to" (lost in translation?). Please try to read [a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead!

Comment: You know what else?  It's also a bad example because of the use of the post-increment operators in the two expressions separated by the comment.  The reason why that makes it a bad example is left as an exercise for you ...

Comment: @davidbak it is funny, but link you gave for operator precedence is wrong

Comment: @Slava - I did that on purpose (\*) to prove you can't rely on random stuff you read on the internet.  Even if it is the first result returned by google.      (*) That's my story and I'm sticking to it ...

Comment: @Slava - huh, I looked into it based on your remark and learned something new: that the precedence of the ternary conditional operator relative to assignment operators is different in C and C++.  Thanks!  (Making that an interview question though would be just nasty.)

Comment: If you're looking for a better tutorial, I would suggest checking [C programming.com](http://www.cprogramming.com/) or [TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/index.htm); they don't get everything right, but I don't remember seeing any glaring errors in either of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source you using is wrong multiple times.

```
int a,b,c; 
a=b++, c++;
```

first of all reading from uninitialized variables leads to UB, so you cannot predict what would be in `a`. Second, even if you would initialize `b` and `c` that expression is equal to:

```
(a=b++), c++;
```

to see behaviour predicted on that site you have to write:

```
a=( b++, c++ );
```

due to higher precedence of `operator=` over comma. Details can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)